# Bluetooth COM port not detected by the processing application (Mac OSx)

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, processing, detection, arduino-ide

I wrote a processing app that can get the Serial data from sensors. It works well with cables(USB), but when I try to integrate a Bluetooth module, it doesn't even detect the Bluetooth serial port.

The Serial.list(), detects all the COM ports except the Bluetooth port. When I run the same with other Serial Port viewers, the BT Serial COM port gets detected. I am able to get the Serial data through other applications on Mac.

Could this be because of the RxTxComm.jar name filters (tty,..)? If yes, then how to write a script within the Processing code to rename the Serial Port and make the jar file detect the Bluetooth Serial Port?

Comment: No, it shouldn't filter TTY, I've seen in show up before in Processing. Are you using the built-in Serial library? And which version of Processing ?

Comment: Thanks, jesses.co.tt... Just figured this out: I changed the rxtxSerial dll file to 2.2 version within the processing library! It works well, now... (Courtesy: arduino forums)

Answer (score 1):

Change the rxtxSerial.dll within the Processing Serial Library with the "rxtxSerail-2.2Fixed" file that's found in the arduino forum:
http://servicios.ried.cl/arduino/

Since Arduino's IDE is based on processing, the same library solves the problem.